# Android Studio - Cannot resolve method 'setText(double)'

Tags: java, android, textview

I have initialized a double variable and want to show it in a TextView. 
The variable name is underlined in red. 
I have tried to parse it to a String, but it did not work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Location currentloc = new Location("currentloc");

    double currlat = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView gpsbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpsView);

        try {
            currlat = currentloc.getLatitude();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hello, an exception was just thrown but I catched it. " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        gpsbox.setText(currlat);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); always call on the top

Comment: Your code should not come before setcontentview...

Comment: And try to read on MVVM implementation in android. The God Object pattern is not adviced when creating android applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to parth this to String by

```
String.valueOf(currlat);
```

I hope it work with you .

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView gpsbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpsView);

    try {
        currlat = currentloc.getLatitude();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello, an exception was just thrown 
     but I catched it. " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    gpsbox.setText(String.valueOf(currlat));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 mistakes in the code.

1. Set content view is used after findViewById which will throw exception.
2. double should be wrapped with String.valueOf() method to converted to string.

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   Location currentloc = new Location("currentloc");

   double currlat = 0.0;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       TextView gpsbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpsView);

       try {
           currlat = currentloc.getLatitude();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Hello, an exception was just thrown but I catched it. " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       gpsbox.setText(String.valueOf(currlat));

   }
   ```

   }